# How to install KDE for different user on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments, kde4, user-profile

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome 2D.

I want to install different desktop environments for different users, there are only 3 different users, 2 of them are in soders list with NOPASSWD

I want one user to use KDE and other to use GNOME.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy.

All you have to do, is install the Desktop Environments you want them to use, and then select them at login time. For each user, the desktop last chosen when they login will be selected every time that user logs in from then on, regardless of whether they are an administrator or not.

Comment: I figured it out few mins ago. Thanks Roland! :)